# Função AND com faixas de valores

Tags: python-3.x

O exercício pede :
Faça um programa que leia 2 notas de um aluno, verifique se elas são válidas e exiba na tela
a média. Uma nota válida deve ser um valor entre 0.0 e 10.0. Para notas inválidas, informe ao usuário e termine o programa.

No meu código, para testar a validade eu usei a função AND combinada com IF.
Vejam o código:

```
n1 = float(input('Informe a primeira nota:'))
n2 = float(input('Informe a segunda nota:'))
if 
    n1 >= 0.0 and n1 <= 10.0:
elif: 
    n2 >= 0.0 and n2 <= 10.0
m = (n1 + n2) / 2;
print('A média das notas é {}.format (m)')
else:
    print('Uma ou mais notas são inválidas.')
```

Ao mesmo tempo, estou meio confuso em como combinar identação de blocos com as funções IF, ELIF, ELSE.
Como vocês me recomendam escrever esse programa?
E porque a função AND não é aceita?

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que você tem erros conceituais bastante básicos sobre Python (Dê uma olhada no link que coloquei nos comentários da sua pergunta). `Elif` deve ser usado como um segundo `if` caso o primeiro não dê certo, o que não é o seu caso, já que a verificação tanto de `n1` e `n2` devem ser verdadeiras.

Assim, você pode fazer ambas as verificações em um mesmo `if`, fazendo os ajustes necessários para a identação do cálculo e mensagem de média. Seu `.format` também está com problemas.

Dê uma olhada de como fica o código corrigido:

```
n1 = float(input('Informe a primeira nota:'))
n2 = float(input('Informe a segunda nota:'))

if n1 >= 0.0 and n1 <= 10.0 and n2 >= 0.0 and n2 <= 10.0:
    m = (n1 + n2) / 2
    print('A média das notas é {}'.format(m))
else:
    print('Uma ou mais notas são inválidas.')
```